# Error al intentar compilar un modulo en Angular

Tags: angular, compilar

Al compilar en visual code con `ng build --watch` de el error

```
 Error: src/app/shared/services/consulta-dev-np/consulta-dev-np.service.ts:4:40 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/nsanchez/eclipse-workspace/perseo/frontalRPA/src/app/shared/models/consulta-dev-np-response.model.ts' is not a module.
```

consulta-dev-np.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IConsultaDevNpResponse } from '../../models/consulta-dev-np-response.model';
import { FormatDatePipe } from '../../pipes/format-date.pipe';
import { AppConfigService } from '../config/config.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConsultaDevNpService {
 ......
}
}
```

consulta-dev-np-response.model.ts

```
import { IConsultaDevNp } from "./consulta-dev-np.model";

export interface IConsultaDevNpResponse {
...
}
```

consulta-dev-np.model.ts

```
export interface IConsultaDevNp {
...
}

export interface ITableConsultaDevNp {
...
}
```

He reiniciado el servidor y el pc y sigo sin poder solucionarlo

Las rutas son las siguientes

```
C:\Users\nsanchez\eclipse-workspace\perseo\frontalRPA\src\app\shared\models
C:\Users\nsanchez\eclipse-workspace\perseo\frontalRPA\src\app\shared\services\consulta-dev-np
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

He optado por eliminar el código que había realizado y eliminar las carpetas ya que reseteando el servidor no me funcionaba ni cerrando el Visual Code.
Al pegar de nuevo el código ya me ha dejado compilarlo todo y se ha resuelto.

Gracias.